# Replacing float with int - how do I do localized input/output?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, math

This is one of those cases where I assume the solution is on google, but I have no idea what the search term even is. Or even which Tags to use on Stack Overflow.

**Situation:**

[Floats are not precise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0). A common trick around it, is to use Integers for the math, then shift the decimal point during output:

If you need 4 decimal places of precision for € (not uncommon in finances), you effectively measure and calculate in milli-Euro. Then during output you shift the decimal left, and cut off the last 2 digits:

So a int `1234567` that is stored, retrieved and processes as a int, would print as/stand for "123.45 €" to the normal end user.

**Problem:**

But how would this interact with localisation? .NET has this awesome part where `Parse()` and `ToString()` look at the current Windows Users Culture setting, to figure out what the decimal separator, group separator and group size is today.

There seems to be no fixed point type in .NET, to do the work for me.

Is there some format string combination I could use to say "shift decimal point 4 left into the number, omit last 2 digits)"? F2 would only add two empty 0 past the decimal point for any int. and "1234567.00 €" is a few orders of magnitude off from "123.45 €"

**My best idea thus far:**

Building my own format string out of the `NumberDecimalSeparator`, `NumberGroupSeparator` and `NumberGroupSizes` from the users culture - but that is just ugly and seems like something I should not be doing. Is there a better day to do it, or is it one of those cases where I have to go for the ugly thing that works?

Comment: Use `decimal` instead?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I could not find any example for using it like that. At it does seem to still be a floating point number, not a fixed point one.

Comment: It is a "floating point" in the sense that it stores where the point is, but it is precise in the sense that `0.1M + 0.2M == 0.3M`.

Comment: And your usage of the word "precise" is an unknown term. You need to *define* what kind of precision you require. Your only option to **always** use a type that is precise is to start working with things like BigInteger or similar, where you have essentially as many digits stored as you need, at the cost of performance. However, `decimal` is suitable for "human numbers", ie. base 10. But yes, eventually it too will be imprecise if you try to store enough digits into it.

Comment: `decimal` has more significant digits than `Int32`, so if you thought `Int32` was good enough, you should be using `decimal`. `decimal` uses base 10 operations, whereas `double` and `float` uses base 2 operations. This means that many of the situations where floating point numbers are unable to represent an accurate number goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
using System.Globalization;

int n = 123456;
string price = "";
string priceW = "";

int i = 0;
foreach(char c in n.ToString())
{
i++;
if(i == n.ToString().Length - 1)
price += ".";
price += c;
}

float rPrice = float.Parse(price, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
priceW = price + "€";
```